# How to create new tag (1 tag per project) for multiple projects using single script in Gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have 4 project in Git, and wants to create new tag with the same name for all projects using single script.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please may you show the effort you've made so far? Also may you add examples of what you expect?

Comment: I have 4 micro-services (4 individual projects) hosted in GitLab and since we are working with agile we have to create new tag like(January_Release) before each release for all microservices.
Generally We used to create tag manually (one by one) from master branch of each project by Git UI.
I am seeking help to do same in single time by using some script instead of going of each project.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can do this with a powershell script. This also works on MAC if you have powershell for mac installed. You can of course write your own script in any other language which does this.

For this script you work you need to have all micro services checked out on your local system, ideally next to each other in your explorer.

To clarify: the `p1, p2...` are the names of your projects (folder names) ... The script navigates into each of these folders and creates a tag version and pushes it to git.

```
Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage="Release Version: v1.xx.y")] [string] $release)


$projects = @('p1', 'p2', ....)

cd 'C:/Path/to/your/root/folder'
$pth = $PWD.Path

foreach ($project in $projects) {
  cd "$($pth)\$project;
  git checkout main
  git pull
  git tag $release
  git push origin $release
}
```

You can call this script with an additional parameter (the tag version). If you just call the script you will be prompted to enter the Tag.